# jQuery unbind event for time

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a shorter way than this to unbind a event for a short time?

```
$('.test').on('click', function () { alert()});
function pauseEvent() {
  $('.test').off('click');
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.test').on('click', function () { alert()});// write the whole event again
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a named function

```
function myFunc() { 
    alert();
}

$('.test').on('click', myFunc);

function pauseEvent() {
    $('.test').off('click', myFunc);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.test').on('click', myFunc);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: one suggestion -  `$('.test').off('click', myFunc);`

Comment: @PranavCBalan - the handler is optional, but sure, it doesn't hurt to add it.

Comment: I think it would help to avoid unbinding any other click event handler attached

Comment: @PranavCBalan - yes, `.off('click')` removes any click event handler, adding the function only removes that function, so it matters if the element  had other click event handlers attached as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a check inside your click event

like

```
$('.test').on('click', function () 
{ 
    if(itsrighttime)
    {
        alert();
    }
});
```

also for unbinding your event

Use $('.test').unbind('click');